# Прекращение работы функции по таймауту без остановки работы главного потока

Tags: python, многопоточность, threading

Предположим у меня есть следующий функционал

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import time
import random

def function():
    time.sleep(random.randint(30, 60))

def scheduled_task():
    function()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
    sched.add_job(scheduled_task, 'interval', seconds=2)
    sched.start()
```

Я хотел бы получить возможность останавливать выполнение функции `function` в том случае, если время выполнения превысило 45 секунд, не останавливая при этом `BackgroundScheduler`
Как вы видите, в функции нет иттераций, поэтому я не могу использовать решение, предложенное [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread)

Я нашел следующее решение, которое позволяет остановить выполнение функции:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import threading
try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread

class Breaker:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def exit_after(self, s):
        """
        use as decorator to exit process if
        function takes longer than s seconds
        """

        def outer(fn):
            def inner(*args, **kwargs):
                print("Отсчет пошел")
                timer = threading.Timer(s, self.quit_function, args=[fn.__name__])
                timer.start()
                try:
                    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
                finally:
                    timer.cancel()
                return result
            return inner
        return outer

    @staticmethod
    def quit_function(fn_name):
        # print to stderr, unbuffered in Python 2.
        print('Время выполнение {0} превысило лимит'.format(fn_name))
        sys.stderr.flush()
        thread.interrupt_main()
```

Но как видно, здесь происходить прерывание работы основного потока, поэтому после применения `BackgroundScheduler` тоже прекращает свою работу.
Возможно ли модифицировать решение выше так, чтобы основной поток не прекращал своей работы?
Возможно, нужно создавать дополнительный поток для работы функции, но в этом случае, я не понимаю как его убить.
Но здравый смысл подсказывает, что должно быть решение, которое позволяет останаливать выполнение затянувшихся операций,но без прекращения работы основого потока.

Comment: multiprocessing.terminate()  не подойдёт ?

Comment: @Интик, и правда, так куда проще)